# Get rid of spring-boot-samples as parent project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

All [Spring Boot sample projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples) have parent project `spring-boot-samples` which is not in central maven repository. So, if I start creating my application in base of any spring boot sample project, then my application should have `spring-boot-samples` as a parent project.

What is the common way to get rid of having `spring-boot-samples` project as a parent of the application?

Comment: Use http://start.spring.io to create a skeleton project base instead of using sample projects.

Comment: Spring boot sample projects are more reach. For example [spring-boot-sample-web-secure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure) contains simple security configuration java code, meanwhile adding "Security" to project in start.spring.io will just add related dependencies to pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run your application as spring boot application you need to provide hint(dependencies) to your Application.

Which is,

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

In your case spring-boot-samples is providing you the support of Spring Boot Application. How?

Open the pom.xml of having artifact id as,

> `spring-boot-samples`

Here you can find above mentioned Spring Boot Identifier(spring-boot-starter-parent) as a parent to spring-boot-samples

Hence coming to your question, if you wish to get rid of said parent you must this dependency as a parent to your current application.

> **`spring-boot-starter-parent`**

Reference(In order):

1. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure/pom.xml
2. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/pom.xml

Note: Reply in comment if more information required.